# Plural followed by singular - "have" or "has"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, relative-clauses, subjects

I'm wondering which of the following is correct:

> Guns are an invention that **have** had an enormous impact on African history.

or

> Guns are an invention that **has** had an enormous impact on African history.

These sentences aren't actually being used in my report, but I decided to create them to save you from the grammatical horror of my actual run-on sentences.

Anyway, I know "have" is used for plural subjects and "has" is used for singular subjects (wrong term, I'm sure), but I'm unsure as to whether the subject is the plural "guns" or the singular "invention." Microsoft Word is suggesting the latter sentence. Is that correct?

Comment: Rewrite to one of: "The gun is an invention that has had..." or "The invention of the gun has had...". I like the second one.

Comment: Yes Jim. The correct answer, if we decide to go with strict, prescriptive rules of concord, is **neither is correct**. _Guns are an invention_ is where the problem lies. There are other situations where concord rules become much more difficult to maintain.

Comment: A situation where concord rules are much more difficult to maintain: *"scissors were an invention that ...".*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The subject of the verb is *an invention* - which is singular, so the verb-form should be too.

Here are a few written instances of ["are an invention that has"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22are%20an%20idea%20that%20has%22&oq=%22are%20an%20idea%20that%20has%22&gs_l=serp.3...1252.1819.18.2822.3.3.0.0.0.0.61.152.3.3.0...0.0...1c.KY2lF6uJvS8&pbx=1&biw=1469&bih=886&cad=cbv&sei=yz0xUMCEL6qH0AXMmoHgDA#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22are%20an%20invention%20that%20has%22&oq=%22are%20an%20invention%20that%20has%22&gs_l=serp.3...18858.22278.0.22817.13.13.0.0.0.0.115.1046.11j2.13.0...0.0...1c.CwHdv34-SSc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=a77c6c655f32ba66&biw=1469&bih=886). Note that Google Books contains no examples of *"are an invention that **have**"*.

Don't bother even thinking about what Microsoft Word recommends or queries - at best it might be useful for flagging up glaring typos/etc. Beyond that, it has no credibility.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: OP's wording of the sentence inclines more toward *have* as it looks like it refers to *guns* not *invention*. If we drop the explanatory *are an invention*, it clearly refers to guns. Not saying it should be *have* but I think it would be better to reword the sentence. What do you think?

Comment: Plus, I didn't down vote.

Comment: I have upvoted you.

Comment: @Noah: exactly — *if* we drop "an invention that", then the verb refers to guns. However, in the sentence at hand, we do *not* drop "an invention that". By your logic, *every* sentence in English is ungrammatical, because if we drop a few words we get gibberish. Besides, rewording is chickening out. It is the opposite of answering. We are here to answer questions, not to dodge them.

Comment: @Noah: Semantically, plural *guns* and singular *an invention* are equivalent (as specified by the linking verb *"are"*). But grammatically, plurality/gender for a "collective/list" agrees with *the last item in the list*.

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually gonna go with Jim's suggestion, but this was certainly helpful and answered my question.

Comment: @user12173: In that case, I don't understand why you posed the question at all. You asked for advice on correct verb agreement *in your example sentence*, which you obviously found problematic. But if you're just going to rephrase it to avoid the issue, surely you could have done that for yourself?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Well, I was planning to rephrase it if "has" was the correct grammar and keep it if "have" was the correct grammar. To me, "has" just sounds more awkward.

Comment: @user12173: oic. Personally I don't find it odd so long as the verb agrees with the last item in the list. But Noah's comment shows you're not alone in finding it difficult to ignore disagreement with anything preceding. And the relative paucity of related examples in Google Books does suggest writers tend to avoid the construction altogether, so maybe you're in good company!

Answer (score 0):

The relative clause with "that ..." refers to *invention* and not to *guns*. So the sentence should be:

> Guns are an invention that **has had** an enormous impact on African history.
>   OR
>   Guns are an invention that **had** an enormous impact on African history.

Answer (score -3):

As the sentence starts, it seems like "guns" is the subject, but as the sentence progresses and comes to "an invention that", "an invention" becomes the subject, so it should be *has*. Moreover, the meaning of the sentence also refers to the invention of the guns, which has had an enormous impact.

Answer (score -3):

Re this sentence (or its proposed sibling): "Guns are an invention that have had an enormous impact on African history.

Guns were not invented; a 'gun' was, however.

When I approach a sentence like this I wonder if the intent is to expound upon 'inventions' have impact on history or 'guns' have impact on history?

Probably the intent is to focus on guns. If so, the stripped down version of this sentence is: "Guns have had an impact on history." And when I do that, then I prefer 'have' rather than 'has'.

Comment: There are 210 000+ Google hits for "are an invention". There seem to be a fair number of relevant hits among these (on the first page alone, 'bikinis are an invention' / 'nanobots are an invention' / 'guns are an invention'.) The perhaps illogical usage is idiomatic.

Comment: Computers are an invention...
The computer is an invention... 

I suppose I can change my opinion on the matter. "Computers are an invention" would be used to suggest something a kin to "this whole classification" of objects rather than the more acute "the computer is an invention" which, somehow feels to me like the statement has less wiggle room, like a more committed statement (ie, probably because the reference is to a specific thing rather than the classification to which the thing belongs).

Answer (score -3):

As I understand it, 'guns are an invention' is a singular abstract idea, so the verb referring to it should also be singular.